# Electron Js, Launching our desktop application when performing a certain task

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, desktop-application

I'm fairly new to electron JS and I was going through the official documentation of the framework, What I do know is that electron offers auto start option out of the box but what I couldn't find was, launching the application automatically if the user performs a certain task for example (At this point in time I want my application to launch if the user joins a meeting from any video conferencing application like zoom, google meets, MS Teams). Thank-you!

At this point in time I was able to play around with the Auto start feature but I wasn't able to find a argument that would allow me to launch the application if I do certain tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use their custom protocol to open app.
Or use `child_process` to open app by executable file.

Comment: I think you've understood the question the other way around. OP wants to open their app when a certain action in *another* app occurs, not open the apps they mentioned from within their app.

Comment: Yes exactly, what I want to do is I want to launch my application when a user joins any web meeting from Zoom, MS teams, Google Meets etc. I wanted to know how I'd able to work with that!